# Presenting a walkway from position A to B in my app

Tags: iphone, gps, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

So I have an iPhone app which should aid the user to find a convenient walkway from his/her own position to a given destination. As I have learnt, MKMapView does not provide an easy way to infer a preferred walking route from A to B.

I can live with terminating my own app and launch the native map application on the iPhone, but in that case I would like to equip the map application with two coordinates so that the user can find his/her way.

Any suggestions to how I should go about this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch the native map app use:

```
NSString *googleMapsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",
                               start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURL];
```

where `start` is the user location  and `destination` is, well, the destination. For walking directions, you can add `&dirflg=w` (still in beta according to wiki). [Here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Directions) are some  more parameters you can use.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, but I really would prefer to open the native map iPhone application, not open the Google API in the safari browser. But maybe the walkway part isn't so easily achieved there?

Comment: That code should open in the native map application, and does for me.

Comment: My bad. Of course it opens in the native map app. Thanks for the perfect answer.